# Embedding vlookup in an excel function

Tags: excel, function, vba, criteria, vlookup

I am trying to correlate data that is pulled from a huge database.  I have no control over the database, so renaming fields is not an option.  I had to separate data from different database tables onto different sheets.  I'm trying to write a function in excel to return specific vlookup values based on a single criteria.  The "itemnum" values are in column A and the "binnum" values are in column K.  I need to be able to use the function for a sheet that has 19,000 unique values for "itemnum".  The problem is, I don't know the syntax for using vlookup in VBA.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Function orders(itemnum, binnum)
If binnum = "ibp" Then
orders = IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(AllLocations!A2,OpenIBP!A:B,1,FALSE)), 0, VLOOKUP(AllLocations!A2,OpenIBP!A:B,2,FALSE))
Else
orders = =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(AllLocations!A2,OpenIST!A:B,1,FALSE)), 0, VLOOKUP(AllLocations!A2,OpenIST!A:B,2,FALSE))
End If

End Function
```

Can anyone help me rewrite this so it works?  I'm in way over my head.  Thanks.

Comment: On my phone so can't help right now but u need to look up R1C1 cell addressing which can be absolute or relative

Comment: One way is to use `orders = EVALUATE("IF(ISNA(..),...)")` for evaluating excel formula. Another way is to use `Application.Vlookup` - [VBA implemantation of VLookup](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vlookup-in-vba/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bridge the gap between the code sample that you had, and the answer that user3423985 gave, here is a variation (assuming that I understand what you were trying to do):

```
Option Compare Text
Function orders(itemnum, binnum)
' look up itemnum in either sheet OpenIBP or sheet OpenIST
' depending on the value of binnum

Dim sheetName As String
If binnum = "ibp" Then
  sheetName = "OpenIBP"
Else
  sheetName = "OpenIST"
End If

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)

' now we can look up something in the sheet:

Dim value

' Look up the value itemnum
' in column A of sheet sh
' return the corresponding value in column 2
' return exact match only
value = Application.VLookup(itemnum, sh.[A:B], 2, False)

' check for error in lookup
If IsError(value) Then
  MsgBox "Item " & itemnum & " not found!"
Else
  orders = value
End If

End Function
```

Comment: If I needed to add a wildcard to the itemnum value in the vlookup how would I do that?

Comment: I am sorry, but `VLOOKUP` itself does not allow for wildcard search. There are other mechanisms in Excel to allow that - for example the `Like` operator. You would have to loop over the cells in the "lookup" column until you found a cell "like" the search criteria (including wildcard), then return the corresponding value from the second column (for example by using `Offset(0,1)`). Do you need help with detailed code sample or can you take it from here?

Answer (score 4):

You can use it like this:

```
V=application.vlookup("A",range("A1:B5"),2,0)
If iserror(v) then
 Msgbox "Fail"
Else
 Msgbox v
End if
```

V is a variant, I am looking for "A" column A, and return value in B